# how to open the existing LWC in VS code

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new to LWC. I want to open the existing LWC which is created by another developer in salesforce. I searched but found nothing helpful.
Help me Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually You need to install `Salesforce Extension Pack` extension in your visual studio code for authorize and access the existing LWC Components.

[This](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-lightning-web-components-developer-tools/install-development-tools) trailhead will help you to install the package.

After package installed, You need to do below things,

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P`, then you need to type/choose
`Create a Project with Manifest` command in VS code (folder to store the files)

After you need to authorize the org by using command `Authorise an Org` for connect into the SFDC org where you already have LWC components.

Then ,Go to `Manifest` Folder --> Right click --> click option `Refresh component from Source` using Manifest. This will refresh the VS Code and get all the existing LWC Components from the connected Org.

Please let me know if it helps.